# Rails Download .csv from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

I have an application where users add a list of URLs and one of my controllers return their HTTP status.

On the view, i render an HTML table based on the object (@results) that is returned from the controller.

I would like to give users the option to download the urls and their status, but I do not want to create an extra request back to the controller as it takes a lot of time to get all the HTTP statuses.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/), apparently for another SO question:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you can export them into CSV file without gem.
[Export CSV](http://richonrails.com/articles/exporting-to-csv-using-ruby-on-rails-3-and-ruby-1-9). Btw, in your question, if you do not want to request your data again, probably you can cache it for your http request or your datas? So, it wont load everything again.